# Issues with background on Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a small issue when trying to set the background color on my bootstrap site. Here is what I have now, with a gray background set on the body:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw827.png

However, I want it to be more like this (inside the red lines should not have a gray background) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw827.png#1

I have played around with it a bit and I haven't gotten any results, and I'm really just not that great at CSS. So if anyone can help me with this, I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using **twitter-bootstrap**, try this code:

```
.container {
    background: #fff; // any color that you want
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I really feel stupid now, I guess I'm tired. Thank you!